# Visual basic installation directory

Tags: visual-studio

I'm making a visual basic 2012 program and I want to store data for example pictures in my applications installation folder. What code should I use to get my applications installation or bin folder so that I can put a folder in bin named pictures that will store the pictures, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt which language you are using!
For `Visual Basic .NET`:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Pictures"
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\Pictures"     System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location) & "\Pictures"
Application.StartupPath & "\Pictures" 'WinForm
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath() 'WebApplication
```

For `C#`:

```cs
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Pictures";
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Pictures";  System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Pictures";
Application.StartupPath + @"\Pictures"; //WinForm
Request.PhysicalApplicationPath; //WebApplication
```

**[Edit]**

Thanks to @Cody Gray for his comment, if you had privilege issue you can store your pictures in the user's `"Application Data"` folder.
To get this folder path in `VB`

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

And in `C#`:

```cs
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Comment: The problem is, you should not have write privileges to the application directory. In modern versions of Windows, regular users won't. This stuff should be going into "Application Data" or the documents folder.

Comment: He didnt mention about this issue, he just wanted the application directory.